# Ruby - Method Issues

Tags: ruby

I created 3 methods here and I need one more to output the final success message instead of the round success message.

```
WINNING_COMBO = {
  'r' => ['sc', 'l'],
  'p' => ['r', 'sp'],
  'sc' => ['p', 'l'],
  'l' => ['sp', 'p'],
  'sp' => ['sc', 'r']
}
```

Comment: Do you really have to post 75 lines of code to illustrate your problem? Try to create a [mcve]

Comment: I just posted it for complete info. you can edit it if you don't want to.

Comment: It is up to you to provide a [minimal viable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We already do a favour answering your questions.

Comment: @mudasobwa: I'd even go as far as to say that it's her _responsibility/duty_, not just "up to".

Comment: Also, paying attention to proper formatting of the code is far more important than worrying about SRP at this stage of your learning.

Comment: I think you need more code now, I don't understand the question being asked :)

Answer (score 2):

```
def display_results(player, computer, counts)
  prompt(
    case
    when counts[:player] == 3 then "You won the game! Congrats!"
    when counts[:computer] == 3 then "Computer won the game. Try again?"
    when win?(player, computer) then "You won this round!"
    when win?(computer, player) then "Computer won this round! You loose!"
    else "It's a tie on this round! No one wins!"
    end
  )
end
```

One should check for a game result *before* round results.

Comment: should I add the count variable here? undefined local variable counts.

Comment: Indeed, I have updated an answer.

Comment: When either the player or the computer won 3x it's still shows the "You won this round"

Comment: Obviously, you should call `count_wins` _before_ `display_results` to update `counts`.